# How to measure performance accurately, excluding background program interference?

Tags: linux, operating-system, profiling

I would measure a program execution time, say, computing fibonacci number, on a Linux desktop. The measure methods could be using the *time* command or *clock*() function in the code, whatever. I am sure that on my computer only this program is running and no other significant program is running. My question is, how can I make sure my measure is accurate and not affected by background program, such as OS interrupt, scheduling, desktop rendering, etc.

---

My first thought is to watch each suspicious aspect which may interfere the measure.

If I worry about interrupt, I should collect all interrupt during my programming running, and analyse their overhead.

If I worry about scheduling, I should analyse the scheduling behaviour, to make sure the scheduler does not incur extra overhead.

If I worry about the desktop rendering in the case of my program use GPUs, which the desktop rendering also uses, it's best to disable this rendering program.

Is this make sense? or any better methods?

---

Relative questions:

[How to get an accurate performance measure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309234/how-to-get-an-accurate-performance-measure?rq=1)

[Getting reliable performance measurements for short bits of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665090/getting-reliable-performance-measurements-for-short-bits-of-code?rq=1)

Comment: Just do it a bunch of times and divide by the number of times. That averages out the noise.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey that makes some sense. But what if the noise always appears in every time.

Comment: Then it's OK. It's no different from running on a slower CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You make a good point, OS interrupt, scheduling and many other things will impact the performance of your program.  But keep this in mind:

When measuring something like complexity in terms of time, you are not looking for specific measurements.  Say you have a simple for loop that runs in O(n) time that you'd like to check and see how long it runs. If you haven't seen time complexity yet, imagine that the complexity of the program is proportional to size, ex 10 elements should take 10 times "longer" than 1 element to complete run time.  When I say you're not looking for specific measurements, I mean you're looking for the time it takes to compute certain input sizes *compared* to other input sizes

So while you are worried about things like OS interrupts, my suggestion is to do something like this:

If you're worried about the efficiency of your program, you can measure the time it takes over the course of several runs, and for several input sizes.
For example, compute a Fibonacci number 100 times (same input), and take the average amount of time it took to complete each run.

Now, increase the size of your input to say twice the original size, and again do a bunch of runs to get the average running time.  What you'll find is that on average, a larger input is going to take longer to compute.  Keep doing this for all sizes of input and you can actually plot the average run times for each input size, and this curve will roughly represent your algorithmic complexity.  It will not be perfect, as most actual functions can not be represented by O(n), O(n^2), there will be some coefficients that may make the curve look strange.

I hope this made sense, and as a last note please keep in mind that you should specify what you're actually looking for.  It sounds like you're trying to find the run time of your program, but what's the point if you're not looking at different input sizes?  What's the point of looking at specific times (in actual seconds) with no comparisons?  Showing that a program ran in 1 second is very meaningless with no context, so I hope this post can give you some more insight on how to show the performance of your program in a more conventional way.

Comment: Thanks. the point is not time complexity, as it's more difficult to get the time complexity for a complicated program than a fibonacci. Rather, the point is how to "accurately" measure a program run time. That means the measure time is mainly dependent on the program's, without including that of OS. In other words, If the program running on a machine without OS, the both measurements should not differ a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found several benchmarking rules from [Systems Benchmarking Crimes](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~gernot/benchmarking-crimes.html#best):

1. Use lots of iterations.
2. Check the standard deviation. If it > 1%, find the reason for this.
3. Ignore the highest or lowest point.
4. Run sufficient warm-up iterations which aren't timed.

In addition, based on some web search, pinning threads on specific cores and setting your process's priority can eliminate scheduling affect. If the program consumes short time, such as below several millisecond, the interrupt affect may be taken into consideration. Otherwise, it can be ignorable.